# What's the best stack for a complex async project

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga, preact

I have a project that needs to call a REST API (auth, and other CRUD endpoints). And I'm wondering what would be the most suitable stack based on preact and redux.

Would you use thunk, sagas or other alternative?
And how can you adapt the preact redux example: https://github.com/developit/preact-redux-example

Comment: I prefer using redux-saga. It is a little complicated to understand than `redux-thunk` but its amazing if used to the fullest. Documentation is very clear : https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/

Comment: Thanks Vishal. Did you already used redux saga with preact ? What's your full stack ?

Comment: I have used redux-thunk in a large scale project. It solved my purpose to the fullest.